# function dearmor(text) does not exist\nLINE 1: ..._on\" FROM \"users_user\" WHERE convert_from(decrypt(dearmor()

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am using a extension in django  `https://github.com/dcwatson/django-pgcrypto`  to encrpt and dcrpt data and when I am doing lookup like

```
Employee.objects.filter(date_hired__gt="1981-01-01", salary__lt=60000)
```

Its giving me errot

```
error message: function dearmor(text) does not exist\nLINE 1: ..._on\" FROM \"users_user\" WHERE convert_from(decrypt(dearmor()
```

I am using  `PostgreSQL 13.0`  and django 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have `pgcrypto` PostgreSQL module installed. Check out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/how-do-i-install-pgcrypto-in-postgresql-8-4/

Comment: I already did  and getting `postgresql-contrib is already the newest version (13+220.pgdg16.04+1).`   and I have created aswell using 
 CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;